# React-Native Fresh Install Compile Error

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I've created a few react-native projects, and since updating to Sierra OSX and Xcode 8, upon opening each project, I get the error:

`Application AppName has not been registered. This is either to due to a require() error during initialisation or a failure to call AppRegistry.registerComponent.`

I've gone back to basics, uninstalled and reinstalled node, reinstalled latest react-native, created a fresh init, and still get the error. I've looked up and removed the custom-compiler-flags, as suggested [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8584#issuecomment-236366222).

This is a real problem, if anyone has any insights I would be very appreciative!

Comment: Can we see the index.ios.js file ?

Comment: I was having this error last night! All I did was to remove the node_modules, install then again and run the app again, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having this error last night! All I did was to remove the node_modules, install then again and run the app again, it worked. – Crysfel